# keras 1D convolution input shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to create a model for 1D convolution, but I cant seem to get the input shape correct. Here is what I have:

```
#this is actually shape (6826, 9000) but I am shortening it
train_dataset_x = np.array([[0, 1, 5, 1, 10], [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]])
#this is actually shape (6826, 1)
train_dataset_y = np.array([[0], [1]])

model.add(Conv1D(32, 11, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape=( len(train_dataset_x[0]), train_dataset_x.shape[1]) ))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1) )
model.add(MaxPooling1D())

model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1) )
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1) )
model.add(MaxPooling1D())


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6826, 9000)
```

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Input to `keras.layers.Conv1D` should be 3-d with dimensions `(nb_of_examples, timesteps, features)`. I assume that you have a sequence of length `6000` with 1 feature. In this case:

```
X = X.reshape((-1, 9000, 1))
```

Should do the job.

Comment: I have 6826 sequences with 9000 features each. Given that information, I could do:

    ` X = X.reshape((-1, 6826, 9000))`

How should I change this bit?

     `model.add(Conv1D(32, 11, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape=( len(train_dataset_x[0]), train_dataset_x.shape[1]) ))`

Should input_shape be:

     `input_shape=(-1,6826, 9000 )`

Comment: How can you have 6K sequences with 9k features each when shape of your x is `(6k, 9000)`? Does each sequence has length 1?

Comment: I think I might be confusing my terminology a little. I have 6k individual samples, or things that I want to train on. Each sample has 9k features. I essentially have 6k bitvectors where each column in the bitvector is a feature. I want a single output predicted from the training. Does that make it more clearer?

Comment: So why do you want to use `Conv1D`. For your task `Dense` layer seems to more accurate.

Comment: Honestly, to try something new out. The samples do have patterns within their bitvectors, so I was curious to see how convolution would handle the patterns and if any new information could be gained from the convolution. Would the timesteps be 1 in this example? nb_of_examples=6000, timesteps=1, features=9000. I would then reshape like so: X.reshape((6826, 1, 9000))?

Comment: So in this case you can use my answer :)

Comment: Ok, sorry to beat a dead horse. I did this:
`X = X.reshape((-1, 9000, 1))`

and my `input_shape=(6826, 9000)`

But now I am getting this error:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (None, 6826, 9000) but got array with shape (6826, 9000, 1)`

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I just read your response to this question, but am having issues matching up shapes in a very similar model architecture here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762895/mismatch-in-expected-keras-shapes-after-pooling. I have exactly the 3D shape you described - # of examples, timesteps, features -  but am getting a similar value check on # of dimensions error.

Comment: For more context, I'm working with a similar dataset. It's audio-based. I think @YuChen, @freed-radical and myself are trying model raw audio.
If we think of it as `(batch_size, time steps, features per time step)` you can frame it either way to the code: it will compile with some elbow grease.
But I found that `(None, 1, 9000)` worked better in my case and produced repeatable convergence