# Mismatch in expected Keras shapes after pooling

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm building a few simple models in Keras to improve my knowledge of deep learning, and encountering some issues I don't quite understand how to debug.

I want to use a 1D CNN to perform regression on some time-series data. My input feature tensor is of shape `N x T x D`, where N is the number of data points, `T` is the number of sequences, and `D` is the number of dimensions. My target tensor is of shape `N x T x 1` (1 because I am trying to output a scalar value).

I've set up my model architecture like this:

```
feature_tensor.shape
# (75584, 40, 38)
target_tensor.shape
# (75584, 40, 1)

inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH,DIMENSIONS))
conv1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
x = conv1(inputs)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
model = Model(inputs, predictions)
opt = Adam(lr=1e-5, decay=1e-4 / 200)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer=opt)
```

When I attempt to train my model, however, I get the following output:

```
r = model.fit(cleaned_tensor, target_tensor, epochs=100, batch_size=2058)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_164 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (75584, 40, 1).

The first two numbers are familiar: 75584 is the # of samples, 40 is the sequence length.

When I debug my model summary object, I see that the expected output from the `Flatten` layer should be `1216`:

[image]

However, my colleague and I stared at the code for a long time and could not understand why the shape of `(75584, 40, 1)` was being arrived at via the architecture when it reached the dense layer.

Could someone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reshaping your target variable to N x T, and it looks like your final dense layer should be 40 rather than 1 (i think).

Comment: This is ingenious! So for seq2seq regression problems, it looks like the target needs to be 2D.